# Javascript only works in chrome and FireFox not IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have been stumped by IE9 bugs lately. I have this function

```
        //return value in the admin/user select in url to get result via $_GET when page reloads
       function toggleView() {
        //parse url to remove all parameters other than ghost_id
         var url = window.location.href.split("&")[0];
         var view_type = $("#toggle_view").val();
        //reload page with view type selected 
         window.location.href = url+"&view_type="+view_type;    
        }
```

What this function is doing is removing the parameters in the url, replacing them with a new parameter and reloading the page so my php can get the new value via $_GET when it reloads.

This works flawlessly in Firefox and Chrome but in IE9 the javascript function is not even being called.  I am wondering if there is an alternative way to do this in jQuery or some other javascript to solve the IE9 issue.

Comment: If the function is not being called, we need to see the code where you attempt to call it.

Comment: my money is on a trailing `,` in a hash definition somewhere...

Comment: Not seeing  what calls this function, I'm guessing that the event you tried to call this function with doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @prodigitalson I think they fixed that in IE 8.

Comment: I don't see an error here. Apart you to solve why this function would not be called in IE but in FF/Chrome (looks strange...), you could check what you get for the url and view type data as your function entries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of all of the parameters, you should split on "?", not on "&".

Comment: "`//parse url to remove all parameters **other than ghost_id**`" -- The error here is assuming `ghost_id` will be the first parameter.

Comment: Ah, you're right, there's a discrepancy in the description and the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when there is an error, all JavaScript is halted at that point.
So there may be nothing wrong with that function and you may have an error elsewhere in your code.